# what is the Beta valuel when simulate a hybrid Geyer model using spatstat, R package

Tags: r, simulation, spatstat

I fit a hybrid geyer model including a hardcore and a geyer saturation components, now I want to simulate the fitted model by rmh() in spatstat, the code is following:

```
mo.X<-rmhmodel(cif=c("hardcore","geyer"), 
               par=list(list(beta=0.0001746418,hc=30.31542),
                        list(beta=1, gamma=0.4195612,r=122,sat=2)), w=Window(A1a2.unmark))
```

there are two beta in simulating the hybrid model: beta for hardcore(), and beta for geyer (),  however, when fitting real data to get a hybrid model, only one beta value provided in the result:

```
unmark.hybrid<-ppm(A1a2.unmark~1,Mo.hybrid, correction="bord")
  unmark.hybrid
    #beta = 0.0001052206
    #Hard core distance:    33.66719
    #gamma:  0.3578263
```

is it right to set the second beta=1?
thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Please provide more details. Preferably a fully reproducible example where you simulate a small dataset and then fit the model to this dataset. For instance `Mo.hybrid` is not defined anywhere in your code.

Comment: thanks Ege, the code and data i used is following: Mo.hybrid<-Hybrid(H=Hardcore(), G=Geyer(105,1))

Comment: the ppp project A1a2.unmark is as following:

Comment: sorry Ege, I can not post the data in comment, so I set a new question,

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a hybrid of several point process models is that the conditional intensity functions of the different models are *multiplied together* to give the conditional intensity of the hybrid.

The parameter called beta in `spatstat` code is the first order potential term. For a stationary unmarked point process, this parameter is a single numerical constant. When you form a hybrid, the beta parameters of the original models are multiplied together to obtain a single number which is the beta parameter of the hybrid.

If you fit a hybrid model to data, the printed output shows only one beta parameter, because any stationary unmarked point process has only one such parameter.

If you define a hybrid model by hand, for simulation by `rmh` as in your example, then you are building a hybrid of several models; you will first have to define each of these models. The model-defining algorithm `rmhmodel` expects each of the models to have its own beta parameter. However, when the hybrid is formed, these numbers will just be multiplied together to give a single beta value which is the first order potential of the hybrid model.

The usual practice is to set all of the beta parameters equal to 1 except the first one. You have done that in your example.

For further information see chapter 13 in the book *Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R*

Comment: another related question: If I fited a real data and got the gamma1, gamma2, to further find the confidence interval of gamma, is it right to simulate 10 time and refit them with data-fiting model fomula'

Comment: as I did in the above example? or should I use simulate(fitted.model) without caring about control the fixed beta and indensity?

Comment: Please post this as a separate question to stackoverflow