# how to determine the second beta value for a hybrid model including H() and Geyer() for simulation using spatstat

Tags: r, hybrid, spatstat

here is a ppp data for fitting hybrid Gibbs model:

```
points
          x       y
1   376.799 376.799
2   376.799 419.136
3   381.033 495.343
4   228.620 232.853
5   215.919 287.891
6  1028.788  38.103
7  1028.788  88.908
8  1384.419  59.272
9  1380.185 110.076
10 1596.104 347.163
11 1600.338 402.201
12 2425.908 605.419
13 2836.577  88.908
14 2836.577 156.647
15 3014.392 215.919
16 3014.392 270.957
17 3048.262 673.158
18 3048.262 723.962
19 2828.110 757.832
20 2845.044 800.169
21 2853.512 850.973
22 2667.229 850.973
23 2637.593 914.479
24 3717.186 554.614
25 3717.186 588.484
26 3717.186 626.587
27 3810.327 254.022
28 3823.029 309.060
29 3823.029 355.631
30 2434.376 668.924
31  770.533 901.778
32  732.430 914.479
33 2493.648 495.343
34 2506.349 541.913
window: rectangle = [0, 4305.67] x [0, 1121.93] units
```

the fitted hybrid model is:

```
Mo.hybrid<-Hybrid(H=Hardcore(), G=Geyer(71,1))
multiple.hybrid<-ppm(A1a2.multiple~1,Mo.hybrid, correction="bord")
multiple.hybrid
#beta = 1.99133e-06
#Hard core distance:    32.90229
#gamma: 9.0508846
```

I want to simulate the fitted hybrid model, the code I would like to use :

```
mo.Ymultiple<-rmhmodel(cif=c("hardcore","geyer"), 
                       par=list(list(beta=1.99133e-06,hc=32.90229),
                                list(beta=1, gamma=9.0508846,r=74,sat=2)), w=W.A1a2)
Y1.m<-rmh(model=mo.Ymultiple, control = list(nrep=1e6,p=1), start=list(n.start=c(34)))
```

however, I am not sure the second beta=1 is a proper syntax. any suggestion? thanks

Comment: sorry for a typo in mo.Ymultiple.<-..r=71,sat=1

Comment: Already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59389278/what-is-the-beta-valuel-when-simulate-a-hybrid-geyer-model-using-spatstat-r-pac